# Error: 'float' object does not support item assignment

Tags: python

I'm programming in python and I don't understand what i'm doing wrong:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from math import exp
x=np.linspace(0.0,4.0,100)
y1=x
for i in range(100):

   y2[i]=1.5*(1-exp(-x[i]))
```

This last line gives me an error that says: float object does not support item assigment. I don't understand how y2 can be considered a float object since it is a list in which every element is calculated with 1.5*(1-exp(-x[i])).

Comment: I don't see any `y2` array declared in your code. Is it a remnant of a global variable from a previous run in the same python engine? (happens with PyScripter)

Comment: Where is `y2` actually initialized?

Comment: You've previously assigned a `float` to `y2`. `y2[i]` only works if `y2` is an array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As *Jean-François Fabre* and *Barmar* have noted, you get this message only if you have y2 already assigned to a float.  IN any case, you'll need to build the list one way or another.

Using the **numpy** array facilities (credit to *John1024*):

```
y2 = 1.5*(1-np.exp(-x))
```

Using a *list comprehension*:

```
y2 = [ 1.5*(1-exp(-x[i])) for i in range(100) ]
```

If these are more advanced than you want to use, you can initialize y2 and build it in your loop:

```
y2 = []
for i in range(100):
   y2.append(1.5*(1-exp(-x[i])))
```

Comment: I doubt that this is the problem. Try `y2[10] = 10` you'll just get `NameError: name 'y2' is not defined`. You're answering the _next_ question.